# How to sort a list of DNS resolvers according to the response time they are taking to resolve my website?

Tags: python, dns, ip, nameservers, resolver

I have this list of DNS resolvers. You can find it here: [DNS resolver list](https://github.com/TheRook/subbrute/blob/master/resolvers.txt). I want to sort this list according to the time they are taking to resolve the IP for my website: [shahsparx.me](https://shahsparx.me). How can I do this?

I prefer the solution to be python based as I am familiar with the DNSPython library.

Comment: Look like you question is not complete. Are you looking for a solution based on shell-script. Or using programming languages like python.

Comment: Added. I prefer Python.